# Does rand() function exist in mikroc?

Tags: c, pic, mikroc

How can I implement the rand() C++ function in mikroC?

I tried rand() but does not work... I don't know how to resolve this

Comment: Read about simple realisations. Also you can use a noise of ADC to improve randomness.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the compiler but rather with the libc you're using.

Comment: I want to implement a tetris game but i don't know how to generate the  shapes randomly

Comment: [**Hoe to generate/wirte random() numbers**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038174/generate-random-numbers-without-using-any-external-functions/15040471#15040471)

Comment: Are you sure? When mikroc really is ANSI-compilant like it claims, it should include rand() in stdlib.h.

Comment: Yes, you are right I can call the rand function.... but it's not working well as I observed, it generates me all the time the same number

Comment: @Zolyboy: Are you calling `srand()`? Are you calling it more than once?

Comment: I called rand() only once until now... but I think that i will have to put it inside an infinite loop

Comment: @Philipp MikroC seems to be a freestanding implementation. Freestanding implementations don't require stdlib.h. See section 4, paragraph 6 of n1570.pdf.

Comment: @Zolyboy: `rand()` is a pseudo-random-number generator. If you don't call `srand` then it is *guaranteed* to always generate the same sequence of numbers in each run of your program. If you do call `srand` then `rand()` will generate a different sequence of numbers according to the value you provide.

Comment: @Steve Jessop I understand but what value should I pass to the srand() seed paramater, cause time(NULL) is not defined

Comment: @Zolyboy: you just need to pass a different value each time you run the program. What makes you say that `time(NULL)` is not defined?

Comment: I tried it like srand(time(NULL)), but this generates error

Comment: maybe I forgot to include something or I don't know... I did not work with mikroC until yesterday

Comment: In C++ I know that i have to include the time.h header but in mikroC i don't know how to do this

Answer (score 1):

If your C implementation conforms to C89, it should include a working `rand()` — maybe you forgot to include `<stdlib.h>`?

If not, it is trivial to write your own `rand`, as long as you don't require very high quality of generated numbers, which you shouldn't for the purposes of TETRIS. This tiny implementation is promoted by POSIX as an option for programs that need to repeat the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers across architectures:

```
static unsigned long next = 1;

/* RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767 */
int myrand(void) {
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return((unsigned)(next/65536) % 32768);
}

void mysrand(unsigned seed) {
    next = seed;
}
```

It will not give you great pseudo-randomness, but it won't be worse than many real-life implementation of `rand()`, either.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this example (or tell me how to create the seed)?

Comment: @DavidRF Link to what example? The posted code is self-contained.

Comment: @user4815162342, I want to know how the seed (param passed to mysrand) is created, maybe using time?, thanks.

Comment: @DavidRF Yes, the classic way to seed the RNG is by invoking `srand(time(NULL))` at program startup.

Comment: That sounds like a great way to create "very predictable random numbers". ;)