# SelectOneMenu doesn't display values extracted from my Database

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I've problems trying to display the field location of a class called "Element" situated in MySql DB. I have to use a SelectionOneMenu to show all the values contained in the field Element.Location. When i run the xhtml page on my server Glassfish in the selectionmenu is shown a string: "elementmanagementDTO.elementDTO@3231313". I don't know what it means. I'll put here down the classes that involved.
I have my `xhtml` page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


<h:head>
<title>Add a Default Package</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:panel header="DefaultPackage Form">
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" id="regGrid">

                <h:outputLabel for="Name">Name:</h:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText id="Name" value="#{addDefaultPackageBean.defpackDTO.Name}" />
                <p:message for="Name" />

                <h:outputLabel for="location">Location:</h:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText id="location" value="#{addDefaultPackageBean.defpackDTO.location}" />
                <p:message for="location" />

                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{addDefaultPackageBean.name}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{addDefaultPackageBean.elelis}" var="ElementDTO" itemValue="#{ElementDTO.location}" itemlabel="#{ElementDTO.location}"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu> 

        </h:panelGrid>

            <p:commandButton value="Add" update="regGrid" action="#{addDefaultPackage.add()}" />
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

My bean page in the dynamic web project:

```
package beans;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

import elementManagement.ElementMgr;
import elementManagementDTO.ElementDTO;
import DefaultPackageManagement.DefaultPackageMgr;
import DefaultPackageManagementDTO.DefaultPackageDTO;


@ManagedBean(name="addDefaultPackageBean") //come viene richiamato 
@RequestScoped
public class AddDefaultPackageBean {

    @EJB
    private DefaultPackageMgr defpackMgr;
    private DefaultPackageDTO defpackDTO;
    private List<ElementDTO> elelis;
    private String name;

    @EJB
    private ElementMgr elemMgr;



    public AddDefaultPackageBean() {


        //defpackDTO = new DefaultPackageDTO();

    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        setElelis(elemMgr.getAllElements());
    }





    public String add() {
        defpackMgr.save(defpackDTO);
        return "home?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public List<ElementDTO> getElelis() {
        return elelis;
    }
    public void setElelis(List<ElementDTO> elelis) {
        this.elelis = elelis;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public DefaultPackageDTO getDefpackDTO() {
        return defpackDTO;
    }
    public void setDefpackDTO(DefaultPackageDTO defpackDTO) {
        this.defpackDTO = defpackDTO;
    }


}
```

ElementmanagementDTO.elementDTO class:

```
package elementManagementDTO;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class ElementDTO {

    @NotEmpty
    private int cost;

    @NotEmpty
    private String description;

    @NotEmpty
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date endingDate;

    @NotEmpty
    private String location;

    @NotEmpty
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date startingDate;

    @NotEmpty
    private String type;

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    //@Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?",
          //  message="invalid email")


    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(int cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getStartingDate() {
        return startingDate;
    } 

    public void setStartingDate(Date startingDate) {
        this.startingDate = startingDate;
    }

    public Date getEndingDate() {
        return endingDate;
    } 

    public void setEndingDate(Date endingDate) {
        this.endingDate = endingDate;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

my managerbean function, situated in ejb, that has the scope to transform the element got in model from the query in a elementDTO:

```
public List<ElementDTO> getAllElements() {
        List<Element> ele=new ArrayList<Element>();
        ele=em.createNamedQuery(Element.FIND_ALL, Element.class)
                .getResultList();
        ElementDTO eleDTO;
        List<ElementDTO> elementDTO=new ArrayList<ElementDTO>();
        for(Element e:ele)
        {
            eleDTO= convertToDTO(e);
            elementDTO.add(eleDTO);
        }
        return elementDTO;
    }
```

my query situated in the model:

```
@NamedQuery(name="Element.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM Element e")
```

and the string used in managerbean:

```
public static final String FIND_ALL = "Element.findAll";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

elementmanagementDTO.elementDTO@3231313 is the [the initial memory address of the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961146/memory-address-of-variables-in-java) in JVM.

And all I can see is that your `itemlabel` of the selectItems should be with a capital **L** `itemLabel`

```
<f:selectItems value="#{addDefaultPackageBean.elelis}" 
               var="ElementDTO" itemValue="#{ElementDTO.location}" 
               itemLabel="#{ElementDTO.location}"/>
```

Comment: Eclipse. It's a school project.

Comment: I hate Eclipse..errors aren't always displayed..i don't understand why professors constrain to use Eclipse as IDE :(