# Using NDK to get an Object's pointing memory address

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, dalvik

I'm currently on a curious trip and I'm trying to create a `native` method that returns the memory address of a Java `Object`.

I have properly configure Android's NDK and my Java method is:

```
public static native String getAddressOf(Object obj);
```

Following that, my native implementation in C:

```
jstring Java_com_danysantiago_andmemutil_MemoryUtils_getAddressOf(JNIEnv *env, jobject clazz, jobject obj) {
    char buffer[11];
    sprintf(buffer, "%p", obj);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buffer);
}
```

But for some reason the returned string address is always the same no matter how much I play around with the app on the emulator. I'm assuming I'm not getting the actual memory pointer or my Java knowledge of how objects are stored in memory is wrong.

**More Background Story:**
I have successfully obtained the address of an `Object` in a standard Java app that runs on my computer's JVM following [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20680667/1305867). I was able to confirm it because I made a heap dump and then used [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to do a search for address which resulted in an instance of my dummy class. However, `sun.misc.unsafe` is not available in Android.

When I try to follow similar steps, making a heap dump of the Android app and searching for the address  that the method returns I get no result, but if I use [OQL](http://visualvm.java.net/oqlhelp.html), that is available with MAT I can find the instance of my dummy class with a different address.

Looking at how using `unsafe` one gets the address makes me wonder that in reality I too, with native code, have to calculate the address inspecting the `Object` fields.

Bring in your knowledge awesome people! Thanks! :)

Comment: This is implementation detail the VM does not necessarily expose, ie, your belief about how an object is stored is not necessarily true, and in this case appears to be untrue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't generally do that.

Dalvik used to pass the object address through JNI, but switched to indirect references in the ICS release.  The motivation for doing so was to make it easier to move objects in the heap, e.g. for a compacting garbage collector.  If app code could get the address of any object visible to JNI, then the GC wouldn't be able to move those objects around, because native code might be accessing them while the GC is running.  (As of Android 4.4 KitKat, objects did not move, but I assume that will change in upcoming releases.)

I think most versions of Android will return the object address from `System#identityHashCode()`, avoiding the need to use JNI, but if that works now I expect it'll break soon as well.

And of course, if you did manage to get an address, it would only tell you what the address *was*, not what the address *is*, because the VM is free to relocate objects at any time.