# What does the '@' (at) sign mean in addresses in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In Java, the '@' sign in an address (e.g., in a printed stack trace) is generally used to represent an instance of an object as "object name" + '@' + System.identityHashCode() (there is a good discussion of this at [Memory address of variables in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961146/memory-address-of-variables-in-java)).

But that doesn't seem to explain the syntax used by Android Studio when it prints out object addresses.

I have a variable, gmap, which has the following value when viewed in the Android Studio Debugger's "Variables" window (when the program has hit a breakpoint).

```
gmap = {com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap@4541}
```

However, when I run the following in the Evaluate Code Fragment window, none of them come up with the value "4541".

```
gmap.toString(): com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap@63676d9
System.identityHashCode(gmap): 104232665
gmap.hashCode(): 104232665

String.format("%x", System.identityHashCode(gmap)): 63676d9
String.format("%d", System.identityHashCode(gmap)): 104232665
```

What does "4541" represent?

UPDATE:
I took another look at a stack trace and noticed that the numbers tend to increase in a sort-of sequential fashion. The following is a partial dump of the mContext variable, as shown in the Variables window when at a breakpoint.

```
mContext = {com.barryholroyd.tapit.ActivityMain@3624} 
 LOGTAG = {java.lang.String@3642} "TAPIT APS"
 bh_aps = {com.barryholroyd.tapit.Bhlogger@3643} 
 mActionBar = null
 mActivityInfo = {android.content.pm.ActivityInfo@3644} 
 mActivityTransitionState = {android.app.ActivityTransitionState@3645} 
 mAllLoaderManagers = null
 mApplication = {android.app.Application@3646} 
 mCalled = true
 mChangeCanvasToTranslucent = false
 mChangingConfigurations = false
 mCheckedForLoaderManager = false
 mComponent = {android.content.ComponentName@3647} 
 mConfigChangeFlags = 0
 mContainer = {android.app.Activity$1@3648} 
 mCurrentConfig = {android.content.res.Configuration@3649}
```

I suspect the @#### values might be offsets into some kind of allocation table or something, but that's just a guess. I'm not sure how/why that would be useful. I'd rather have them be the hash code or something else that would help me identify the particular class instantiation easily.

Barry

Comment: That number isn't guaranteed to be the same from one run to the next.  I wonder if the variables view is running in (or reporting on) a different VM from the Evaluate Code Fragment window.  That could account for the difference.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I don't think that's it, but I do have some new information. I'll update the question.

Comment: What you have interpreted is correct for `Oracle JVM` not for `Dalvik VM` on which the bytecodes are generated. It has fixed set of Registers which ranges from 0-65535. If you want to learn more you can visit this [link](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html)

Comment: Excellent -- thank you! If I understand correctly, the #### is actually an identifier for the register which stores the value -- is that correct? (That's a lot of registers.) That seems like a pretty useless thing to provide to developers since we can't correlate it with the stuff that we have access to (such as hashCode()).