# How to verify an instance of a List is not another List instance?

Tags: kotlin, hash-code-uniqueness

I have a list

```
var theDataList: List<Data> // populated with some data
```

and made a copy of it

```
val copy = theDataList.toMutableList()
```

downstream in the code it would like to verify whether it is the copy one or the original one

the `.hashCode()` returns same for both

If just want to use Log to print out, how to do it?

the `Log.d("+++", "theDataList: ${theDataList.hashCode()},  copy: ${copy.hashCode()"})`   print out same number.

And `Log.d("+++", "copy: ${copy}")` prints out the list content

Comment: @Innyf pls choose an answer :)

Comment: @Willi Mentzel, thanks for your help, but still dont get the answer for what if I want print out something like the address or internal id for this `theDataList`? the hashCode are same for copy and the orginal, and Log.d("+++", "$theDataList")  prints out the content of the list, and Log.d("+++", "${theDataList.hashCode()}")  is same as printout out the Log.d("+++", "${copy.hashCode()}")

Comment: @Iannyf there is nothing like an address value you could really rely on. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1961150/1788806

Comment: so the answer is "no, it cannt show the identity in the Log or println".

Comment: @Iannyf yes, I edited my answer to include that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

The hash code for both lists is the same because it is based on the data in the list, which is the same.

**Solution:**

What you actually want is to compare the references of both lists. You can do that with Kotlin's [referential equality operator](http://The%20hash%20code%20for%20both%20lists%20is%20the%20same%20because%20it%20is%20based%20on%20the%20data%20in%20the%20list,%20which%20is%20the%20same.%20What%20you%20actually%20want%20is%20to%20compare%20the%20references%20of%20both%20lists%20(see%20Eugene's%20answer)) `===`.

```
theDataList === copy // false
```

There is no ID/hash you can rely on to identify an object on the JVM the way you want. For more info take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1961150/1788806).

Comment: Thx, but what to use to show it with the log if the hashCode can't differ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `===` operator to compare references are the same (not calling `equals` method)