# When debugging, what does the object instance representation "result = {SomeClass@816}" mean?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, instance

I am debugging my java program, and I have some instance "instance1" of class called "SomeClass". When I evaluate the variable "instance1", it says result = {SomeClass@816}.

What does "@816" actually mean?

I know it is not for sure the hashCode(), is it the instance memory address? 
If so, how can I "see" the instance address in code? Which method to call on the object itself?

Note: I am using IntelliJ Idea

```
public class SomeClass {

private String name;
private int id;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.name + this.id;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    String objName =  ((SomeClass) o).name;
    return this.name.equals(objName);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return this.name.hashCode();
}
```

Comment: Could this answer help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1961150/11012656

Comment: The "address"? You're seeing the `toString` representation of whatever it is--how that is constructed varies, but it is generally a representation of the hash code by default. There is no (meaningful) "address" available to the user unless you're specifically debugging a JVM, which you almost certainly are not.

Comment: @DaveNewton but I am already overriding toString() method and hashCode() method  (toString returns value of "name" field and hashCode() returns 0), and still I do not know where does the "@816" comes from ...

Comment: You commented that _I am already overriding toString() method and hashCode() method_ Apparently not. Please [edit] your question and post the code of your `SomeClass` class. Also, how are you debugging? Is it through some IDE, like Intellij?

Comment: @Dave_dev I don't know what your IDE uses for a debugger view of the class in question. Unrelated, but hard-coded hash codes have the potential to introduce issues.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ Idea, yes... and also, I changed the implementation of the hashCode(). There is edit in the question

Comment: In the IDEA debugger window, if you right click on the variable name you should be able to change the repesentation method that it's using to get the displayed value

Comment: IIRC, IntelliJ (or maybe Java), attaches a simple increasing id to each instance of a class while debugging. That is what the debugger shows here: the (simple) class name and that id.

Comment: So, the conclusion is - it is notting important or code-connected :) It is just some ID attached from IntelliJ or JVM

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Memory address of variables in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961146/memory-address-of-variables-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That 816 belongs to the `identityHashCode` (method `System.identityHashCode()`) of every java Object.

Doesn't matter wether **your Class** **overrides** or not the `hashcode()` method, since `identityHashCode()` will call the natural `hashcode()` method of **your Object**.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns the same hash code for the given object as would be returned
>   by the default method hashCode(), whether or not the given object's
>   class overrides hashCode()

Comment: Ok, now in the debbuger window is SomeClass@796, and when I am calling System.identityHashCode(someClass) it returns 1659791576...

Comment: nevermind the number given : ). The thing is, that id after the @ is out of your scope

Comment: Thanks, that helped !