# How to sort objects in a collection by the memory location?

Tags: java, sorting, memory-address, comparable

```
package com.company;

import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Main {

    public static class Node implements Comparable<Node>
    {
        public int value;

        public Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Node node) {
            // Memory location of this - memory location of node.
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TreeSet<Node> set = new TreeSet<>();

        Node n = new Node(5);

        set.add(n);

        for (var node : set)
            System.out.println(node.value);
    }
}
```

Here I have a `Node` class. I want to be able to insert the nodes in a `TreeSet` and sort them by their location in memory. How can I return the difference of the memory locations in the function `compareTo`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Memory address of variables in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961146/memory-address-of-variables-in-java)

Comment: Firstly, how do you define "*position in memory*"? Memory is not just like a big array with integer indices, it's a hierarchy ranging from ultra-fast registers to increasingly slower caches, ram, disk, etc. Secondly, the JVM acts as an abstraction layer so it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory location of an object is not available to a (pure) Java program.

Even if you use native code or `Unsafe` to get the location of an object, there is no guarantee that the GC won't move it ... without any notice.  So if you were to order the objects in a collection by their memory address, the collection would not stay ordered.

On the other hand, you could use `System.identityHashCode(Object)` to get a 32 bit code that will not change for the lifetime of the object.  Even if the GC moves the object.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to order elements by their memory address. You can't rely on that cause it can change over time. [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1961150/4412851)