# Why is python automatically sorting an array I didn't tell it to sort

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

Why is python sorting an array I'm not asking it to sort, and how do I get it to stop?

For example, I have an NumPy array **A**:

```
A = np.array[4, 7, 1, 3, 2], [3, 2, 4, 2, 1]
```

I wish to sort this array, but preserve its original structure so I can index it later. So my idea was to make a copy of the array and sort the copy:

```
B = A
B.sort()
```

Why is it then, that when I print **A** after this sort command, it prints the sorted array? Even though I never called sort on it?

```
print(a)


[[1 2 3 4 7]
[1 2 2 3 4]]
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: `B = A` **does not** create a copy.

Comment: Correct, B just references the location in memory where A is stored, so they are pointing to the same thing.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to make a copy?

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think that's a thing that's hard for people to wrap their head around with Python:  `=` **never** makes a copy.  If you want a copy, you have to be explicit about it.  See [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): Explicit is better than Implicit.

Comment: @LiamFiddler I understand what you are saying, but talking about "referencing the same memory location where A is stored" is not a useful level of abstraction in Python. Python is a high-level language, there is no direct interaction with locations in memory or pointers. Names refer to objects. Assignment statements bind names to objects. `A = B` binds the object referenced by `B` to the name `A`. Consider an implementation of Python on the JVM, where objects aren't guaranteed to stay in the same location in the heap, then talking about "locations in memory" just becomes nonsensical

Comment: @Yoddlenod read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Do you have a link about objects not guaranteed to stay in the same location in the heap? Sounds interesting.

Comment: @HeapOverflow it's nothing particularly crazy. The JVM, particularly the garbage collector, is free to move objects around, an in fact, it does. So here's a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961146/memory-address-of-variables-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, B just points to the same location in memory as A, so modifying B also modifies A. You need to call the .copy() method, as shown below:

[image]